# Most used tags of author - mysql normalised database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can't get this query to work. I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
SELECT tags.*
FROM blog_tags AS tags 
LEFT JOIN blog_items AS items ON (items.authorid = 4) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN blog_items_tags AS itemstags ON (itemstags.itemid = items.id) 
GROUP BY tags.id
```

What I want is to get all the tags an author has used in articles.

For the idea: The databases are:

- blog_tags (id, title)
- blog_items (just articles with field id, authorid, etc...)
- blog_items_tags (itemid, tagid).

What's the correct statement? (I'm not very familiar with mysql)

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: no, mysql just keeps processing on this one. Other ones give errors like: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN blog_items_tags AS itemstags ON (itemstags.itemid = items.id)' at line 4

Comment: Please describe how you are running the query -- a PHP page?  a query admin program?  phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a join condition (your blog_tags table is not used anywhere). In addition, you need an `INNER JOIN` as you want only the tags that were used, not all tags, and related info.

Here is corrected query:

```
SELECT tags.*
FROM blog_tags AS tags 
INNER JOIN blog_items_tags AS itemstags ON (itemstags.tagid = tags.id) 
INNER JOIN blog_items AS items ON items.authorid = 4 AND items.id = itemtags.itemid 
GROUP BY tags.id
```

Comment: YES! This is it! The final query looks like this, for who's interested: "SELECT tags.*, COUNT(*) AS tagcount FROM blog_tags AS tags INNER JOIN blog_items_tags AS itemstags ON (itemstags.tagid = tags.id) INNER JOIN blog_items AS items ON (items.authorid = 4 AND items.id = itemstags.itemid) GROUP BY tags.id ORDER BY tagcount DESC, RAND() LIMIT 10" Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I always use subqueries in cases like this.  You can use joins, too, but I've never been as comfortable writing those (and I think they evaluate to the same DB lookup anyway - but correct me if I'm wrong!), so I'd write something like this:

```
SELECT tags.* FROM tags WHERE id IN (
    SELECT tagid FROM blog_items_tags WHERE itemid IN (
        SELECT id FROM blog_items WHERE authorid = 4
    )
);
```

It's a bit messier than a join, but It makes more sense to me when I go back and read it - hope this helps!

**Edit:**  If you want the number of times each tag was used, you can add a `COUNT` and a `GROUP BY` to the query:

```
SELECT tags.*, COUNT(*) FROM tags WHERE id IN (
    SELECT tagid FROM blog_items_tags WHERE itemid IN (
        SELECT id FROM blog_items WHERE authorid = 4
    )
) GROUP BY tags.title;
```

Comment: He, thanks. Tried it and works. But though I'm not familiar with this notation; what's the correct way when using joins? (I want to count the times an tag is used by the author too and add it to the query; can't see how that's done here)

Comment: When using sub-queries for a large database - make sure your mysql server uses indexes correctly (run the query with EXPLAIN). There are bug reports that this approach is slow because indexes are not used, and it is recommended to use JOINs for these types of application.

Comment: @Serge - Cool - thanks for the info.  I'll look out for that in the future.  Cheers!

Comment: @Bert - I've added a counting version to my answer.  And if you want to see how it's done with joins, check out Serge's answer (I think you can just add a `COUNT(*)` to his, too).  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Used the sollution of Serge; final query in comment to his answer. Your sollution also works, but I like the joins better and it seems faster (but I might be mistaken about that). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshoot by running simpler versions of this query, then building up.  Start with

```
SELECT tagid FROM blog_tags
```

Then work up.

In particular, try removing AS.  This flavor of SQL may require it to be absent:

```
SELECT tagid FROM blog_tags tags
```

Comment: Yes, but most of the time I don't get an error, I just get all the tags back, instead of only the tags of the author. The query is not doing it's job. Can't figure it out yet.

Comment: Ah.  This is necessary info for your post.

Comment: Suggest you make the query display fields from other tables besides tags, so you can see what's happening.  I expect you will work this out by trying variants.

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work. Problem was with the joins. Thanks anyway for the tips!